# How to get IDLE handle or change its memory protection?

Tags: windows, driver, code-injection, virtual-memory, windows-kernel

I'm trying to inject some code into the IDLE process.

For doing this I need to change the virtual memory protection of the target region. If I'm working with the usual process it can be done with `ZwProtectVirtualMemory`. It is an undocumented function and it requires a process handle, which I can get from `ZwOpenProcess`, which, in turn, requires PID.

But IDLE's PID is 0, and `ZwOpenProcess` doesn't accept it.

I think, there should be another function, that can change protection, but I can't find it. In addition, I'll need to allocate memory in IDLE and it also impossible without process handle.

So, how can I get an IDLE handle or change protection without it?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Maybe reaching into another process to mangle its memory isn't the best way to do it.

Comment: I'm doing a study project from my university, that is titled "Code injection in the IDLE process", so I don't have any more general targets...

Comment: How do you know IDLE's PID is 0?  I have IDLE running right now, and Task Manager shows 2 Python processes - neither has a PID of 0.

Comment: "Idle" is not a real process, merely a place-holder in Task Manager to report unused cpu time.  Also visible from the docs for GetProcessId(), it returns 0 as a error indication.  Hard to guess why a university would give an assignment like this, other than that failure is the intended goal.

Comment: I guess I wasn't accurate enough... I meant [System Idle Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Idle_Process), not Python IDLE

Comment: @hans-passant, but I can change idle assembly code from WinDbg, so it is real to set ```jump``` to any third-party code. The question is how to do this programmatically, without WinDbg.

Comment: @HansPassant - you mistake. in system exist `EPROCESS` object with *Idle* name, and `UniqueProcessId == 0`. so this is real process. but this is very special process, even not included to `PsActiveProcessHead` list. and this process have no user mode memory, *PEB*, etc. *ntdll.dll* not mapped here, can not be user mode thread created. so inject dll impossible here

Comment: @RbMm, wait, I didn't talk about injecting DLL, I just want to execute some third-party ASM instruction there. There is KiIdleLoop function inside the idle process. I found it in WinDbg and can rewrite jump instruction there, so the function will call my code from the nearest "code cave".

Comment: @2sha - the memory is common for kernel. `KiIdleLoop` function not inside process. it inside *ntoskrnl.exe*. your question at all no sense. you want patch kernel (and soon got bsod) for execute some code on thread which belong to `PsIdleProcess` ( `=&KiInitialProcess`) ?

Comment: and as note `ZwProtectVirtualMemory` work only with user memory space, it not work for kernel. so this api anyway not help you. for modify read-only kernelmode memory use `MDL` - for map required memory as writeble

Comment: @RbMm, yes, I want to path kernel... I didn't know about ```ZwProtectVirtualMemory```, so thank you, I'll try to use ```MDL```. It will be great if you have a working example of it.